Flutter Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in
While I am trying to generate apk it gives me following error
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in /Users/admin/StudioProjects/st-ma-supervisor/build/app/outputs/mapping/dotRelease/missing_rules.txt.
ERROR: R8: Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication (referenced from: void io.flutter.app.FlutterPlayStoreSplitApplication.<init>() and 5 other contexts)
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallException (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.lambda$installDeferredComponent$1(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Exception))
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager (referenced from: com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.splitInstallManager and 5 other contexts)
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManagerFactory (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.<init>(android.content.Context, io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI))
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallRequest$Builder (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.installDeferredComponent(int, java.lang.String))
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallRequest (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.installDeferredComponent(int, java.lang.String))
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallSessionState (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager$FeatureInstallStateUpdatedListener.onStateUpdate(com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallSessionState) and 1 other context)
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.<init>(android.content.Context, io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI) and 2 other contexts)
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnFailureListener (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.installDeferredComponent(int, java.lang.String))
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnSuccessListener (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.installDeferredComponent(int, java.lang.String))
Missing class com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task (referenced from: void io.flutter.embedding.engine.deferredcomponents.PlayStoreDeferredComponentManager.installDeferredComponent(int, java.lang.String) and 1 other context)
Missing class java.awt.Color (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.AwtCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object) and 3 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.Font (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.AwtCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object) and 3 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.Point (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.AwtCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object) and 3 other contexts)
Missing class java.awt.Rectangle (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.AwtCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object) and 3 other contexts)
Missing class javax.money.CurrencyUnit (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.support.moneta.MonetaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object) and 1 other context)
Missing class javax.money.Monetary (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.support.moneta.MonetaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object))
Missing class javax.ws.rs.Consumes (referenced from: com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider)
Missing class javax.ws.rs.Produces (referenced from: com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider)
Missing class javax.ws.rs.core.Response (referenced from: void com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider.<clinit>())
Missing class javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput (referenced from: void com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider.<clinit>())
Missing class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader (referenced from: com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider)
Missing class javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter (referenced from: com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider)
Missing class javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider (referenced from: com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonProvider)
Missing class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable (referenced from: com.alibaba.fastjson.support.jaxrs.FastJsonAutoDiscoverable)
Missing class org.javamoney.moneta.Money (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.support.moneta.MonetaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.joda.time.DateTime (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int) and 2 other contexts)
Missing class org.joda.time.DateTimeZone (referenced from: void com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.<clinit>() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class org.joda.time.Duration (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int))
Missing class org.joda.time.Instant (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.joda.time.LocalDate (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int) and 1 other context)
Missing class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int) and 2 other contexts)
Missing class org.joda.time.LocalTime (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int))
Missing class org.joda.time.Period (referenced from: java.lang.Object com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.deserialze(com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, int))
Missing class org.joda.time.ReadablePartial (referenced from: void com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.write(com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer, java.lang.Object, com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.BeanContext) and 2 other contexts)
Missing class org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat (referenced from: void com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.<clinit>() and 2 other contexts)
Missing class org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter (referenced from: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JodaCodec.ISO_FIXED_FORMAT and 25 other contexts)
Missing class springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json (referenced from: void com.alibaba.fastjson.support.springfox.SwaggerJsonSerializer.write(com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Type, int))

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyDotReleaseWithR8'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete
> Blockquote

But when I create debug apk, everything works fine. In missing file, which compiler is pointing, it is only suppressing. After suppressing these warnings, when I try to run the app it starts crashing.
This is miss_rules.txt
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallException
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManagerFactory
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallRequest$Builder
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallRequest
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallSessionState
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnFailureListener
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.tasks.OnSuccessListener
-dontwarn com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task
-dontwarn java.awt.Color
-dontwarn java.awt.Font
-dontwarn java.awt.Point
-dontwarn java.awt.Rectangle
-dontwarn javax.money.CurrencyUnit
-dontwarn javax.money.Monetary
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.Consumes
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.Produces
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.core.Response
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter
-dontwarn javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider
-dontwarn org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable
-dontwarn org.javamoney.moneta.Money
-dontwarn org.joda.time.DateTime
-dontwarn org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
-dontwarn org.joda.time.Duration
-dontwarn org.joda.time.Instant
-dontwarn org.joda.time.LocalDate
-dontwarn org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
-dontwarn org.joda.time.LocalTime
-dontwarn org.joda.time.Period
-dontwarn org.joda.time.ReadablePartial
-dontwarn org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
-dontwarn org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
-dontwarn springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json

I also have tried adding android.disableMinifyLocalDependenciesForLibraries=false but it didn't work out, here is my gradle.properties
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableD8=true
android.enableR8=true
android.disableMinifyLocalDependenciesForLibraries=false

Your help will be appreciated. If you need build.gradle I will share. Thank you

By default R8 requires all referenced classes to be present when compiling and reports the error you see if that is not the case.
Missing classes typically comes from dependencies which might require additional dependencies are designed for running on the JVM.
Here adding Joda-Time should get rid of the failures for org.joda.time classes and the com.google.android.play.core classes by finding the Google Library with these classes. However, for the java and javax classes there is no way around adding the -dontwarn as you did.
If the app then crashes you will have to look at the crash to see if it is related to the missing classes. If it is trying to access some of the missing classes they will have to be added as dependencies. For the java and javax classes that is not possible for Android, and the library where they are used cannot be use don Android.
